# Why isn't my file upload working in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom module and I want a field to upload a picture. Chrome appears to upload the file, but it's not working and I get the error below. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
function nafa_adoption_form($form_state)
{
  $form['#attributes'] = array('enctype' => "multipart/form-data");

  ...

  $form['picture'] = array(
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Picture'),
    '#size' => 20,
    '#upload_location' => 'public://uploads'
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save'),
  );




  return $form;
}
```

Submit function:

```
function nafa_adoption_form_submit($form, &$form_state) 
{


  dvm($form_state['values']); //field 'picture' is blank

  $file = file_load($form_state['values']['picture']);

  $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;

  file_save($file);

  $fileid = file_load($file);

  variable_set('adoption_picture', $fileid->uri);

  if ($file)
  {
    drupal_set_message("File uploaded ");
  }

  else
  {
    drupal_set_message("File could not be uploaded");
  }

  drupal_set_message(t('Your form has been saved.'));
}
```

I also get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$uri in file_save() (line 573 of /home/amn7940/nafa.achristiansen.com/includes/file.inc).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [docs for the `file` element type](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#file) you'll notice there is no `#upload_location` property. This is because when using a `file` type you are expected to move the temporary file into the permanent location yourself.

From the code you're using in your submit function I'm pretty sure you're looking for the [`managed_file`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) type. If you use that instead your code should start working perfectly:

```
$form['picture'] = array(
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => t('Picture'),
  '#size' => 20,
  '#upload_location' => 'public://uploads'
);
```